# Regex: how to remove whitespace except for a certain string

Tags: c++, regex, wxwidgets

I have this certain string:

```
node=A B && details=blah blah&&node=bl ah||details = blah again
```

Now what I want is to remove every whitespace except when it is at `details=[^&|]+[&|]`

Like this:

```
node=AB&&details=blah blah&&node=blah||details=blah again
```

Even spaces in equal should be removed.

What should the regex should be?

I have tried this `([ \t\r\n\v\f])&^(details=[^&|]+[&|])` but it doesn't work.

NOTE: I am using wxWidgets for this.

Comment: Except when ? Can you be more clear ? and the last `details` doesn't have any `&&` or `||` at the end ?

Comment: I don't think there is a one step procedure with regular expressions for this as their power is limited especially with respect to negations. The ^ usually only works with character groups in []. However, what could work is a 3 step procedure: 1. extract the values of "detail=...." and replace them with special placeholders. 2. replace the spaces in the remaining string. 3. insert back the values of detail=... to the placeholder positions.